# Can't connect to Dockerized MariaDB ColumnStore database from host machine

Tags: mysql, mariadb, docker, containers

I have setup a MariaDB ColumnStore Database as described in the [MariaDB ColumnStore Quick Start](https://github.com/mariadb-developers/mariadb-columnstore-quickstart) guide. The guide is missing some steps so these are the exact steps I took:

```
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 --name mcs_container mariadb/columnstore

docker exec -it mcs_container bash

yum install git wget

git clone https://github.com/mariadb-developers/mariadb-columnstore-quickstart.git

./get_flight_data.sh

mariadb

        CREATE USER 'user1'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '<PASSWORD>';

        GRANT ALL ON travel.* TO 'user1'@'%';

Exit mariadb client

./create_and_load.sh 127.0.0.1 3306 user1 <PASSWORD>
```

I can query the DB from within the container. Now, I want to connect to the DB from my local Windows 11 machine through TCP. But every time I try to connect to it using a local MySQL client I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.9\bin>mariadb --host 172.17.0.2  --port 3306 --user app_user -p
Enter password: ********
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on '172.17.0.2' (10060)
```

*Edit*: I am using Docker Containers IP Address `172.17.0.2` in the above request since I am trying to connect to the server/DB that is inside the container. I found the IP address through the following command:

```
docker inspect -f "{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}" mcs_container
```

For further clarity, the diagram below illustrates the setup and problem, the connection (middle arrow) is what is failing at the moment.
[image]

*Edit End*

I did some trial and error through the research I found online but I have reached an impasse. I don't know what I am missing. Here are a few things I have tried:

1. Followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OabTOPOU2RU&t=319s) video as well as section 2.3 of [this](https://www.baeldung.com/docker-cant-connect-local-mysql) article detailing how to connect to a containerized MariaDB/MySQL server. No luck.
2. I also looked into bind addresses as mentioned [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/). But as mentioned in this more recently answered [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/299373/allowing-remote-connections-to-mariadb-docker-conatiner), bind addresses may not be the problem. And I don't exactly understand what I am messing with here. So I left it alone for now.
3. Last possibility I could think of is that it could be a firewall issue, as mentioned [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/). I use Kaspersky Internet Security - I tried disabling the firewall but again that made no difference.

I am new to docker, sorry if I have overlooked something small and obvious. Any help will be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'm also still new to containers, but I can see that you have created the container and mapped port 3306 on localhost to 3306 inside the container. So, I think you should be trying to connect the mariadb client to localhost:3306 (or maybe 127.0.0.1:3306) rather than that other IP address?

Comment: How did you obtain the IP address 172.17.0.2 and why do you think it's the one to connect to?

Comment: @dbdemon 172.17.0.2 is docker IP address. In my understanding, that is basically telling the MySQL client I want to connect to the MySQL DB that is inside the Docker container. If I specify localhost instead, it would try to connect to the DB on my local machine, and it would also fail since the user doesn't exist in the local machine.

Comment: @mustaccio I have edited my question clarify how I obtained the IP address 172.17.0.2. And the reason I am using it is because that is the IP address of the docker container. This is telling the MySQL client on my local machine to connect to the MySQL/MariaDB server that is inside the container.

Comment: If you have a MySQL or MariaDB running in the computer, it is already using 3306.  In that case "-p 3306:3306" will conflict.  Map to another port number.

Comment: Does your Windows host have an address on the 172.* network? I'm not  familiar with running Docker on Windows, but I suspect that your containers are in fact running in a [sort of] virtual machine running on your Windows host, so you need make sure that the "VM"'s network is reachable from Windows.

Comment: @RickJames I only had [MariaDB client](https://mariadb.com/products/skysql/docs/connect/clients/mariadb-client/) running in the computer. I uninstalled it and used the [MariaDB Connector/Python](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-connector-python/) instead to test the connection. And like you suggested, I also I tried to map to a different port - "3307:3306". Neither worked. Still getting the same error.

Comment: @mustaccio have put a diagram to explain my setup. Hopefully it would give more context. How can I make sure the VMs network is reachable from Windows?

Comment: Trying to install Mariadb/Columnstore from docker hub and it does not exist. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: @pantonis From MariaDB 10.5.4, ColumnStore is available with the MariaDB server image itself, not separately. So you should be able to install it using the following command: `docker run -d  --name mcs mariadb/columnstore`. For further guidance, [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/running-mariadb-columnstore-docker-containers-on-linux-windows-and-macos/) and [this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-columnstore/) should help.

Comment: No it's not. the link to dockerhub gives 404

Comment: Not sure why that is the case. My guess is they may be updating the image/documentation. IDK. Anyways, your question may not get many eyes this far into this comment section. Perhaps ask a new question. **Side note:** This may or may not be  useful to you but, [this](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-columnstore-docker) seems to be the (not official) mariadb-columnstore-docker git repository from mariadb.